# Pandas to_timedelta incoherent values return

Tags: python, pandas, timedelta

I'm trying to do something very simple, I have a DatetimeIndex on a dataset and I want to keep the last 12 months only based on the most recent entry.

My data : AU, contains one entry by month and the date is always the firt day of the month.

Now, when I do this :

```
mask = au.index >= max(au.index) - pd.to_timedelta(12, unit = 'M')
pd.unique(au[mask].index)

Out[5]: 
array(['2018-11-01T00:00:00.000000000', '2018-12-01T00:00:00.000000000',
       '2019-11-01T00:00:00.000000000', '2019-10-01T00:00:00.000000000',
       '2019-09-01T00:00:00.000000000', '2019-08-01T00:00:00.000000000',
       '2019-07-01T00:00:00.000000000', '2019-06-01T00:00:00.000000000',
       '2019-01-01T00:00:00.000000000', '2019-05-01T00:00:00.000000000',
       '2019-04-01T00:00:00.000000000', '2019-03-01T00:00:00.000000000',
       '2019-02-01T00:00:00.000000000'], dtype='datetime64[ns]')
```

I get my latest month and the past twelve months so 13 months overall. Which is fine, i thought it was just a question whether the calculation include or exclude the last month.

So I change my code to :

```
mask = au.index >= max(au.index) - pd.to_timedelta(11, unit = 'M')
pd.unique(au[mask].index)

Out[9]: 
array(['2019-11-01T00:00:00.000000000', '2019-10-01T00:00:00.000000000',
       '2019-09-01T00:00:00.000000000', '2019-08-01T00:00:00.000000000',
       '2019-07-01T00:00:00.000000000', '2019-06-01T00:00:00.000000000',
       '2019-01-01T00:00:00.000000000', '2019-05-01T00:00:00.000000000',
       '2019-04-01T00:00:00.000000000', '2019-03-01T00:00:00.000000000',
       '2019-02-01T00:00:00.000000000'], dtype='datetime64[ns]')
```

Now i get only 11 months back instead of 12 as expected.

Does anybody know why ?

Thank you

PS : I understand that there would probably be a way to do this using relativedelta. But I'm curious to understand pandas' behaviour.

Comment: actually i cant reproduce that behavior. it returns 12 month for the second mask

Comment: in term of `timedelta`, `year` is fixed as approximately `365.25` days. And I guess `month` would be `year/12`, so subtracting 12 months wouldn't do exactly what you want. You should use `pd.DateOffset`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you @Quang Huong, using this solved my problem :

```
mask = au.index >= max(au.index) + pd.DateOffset(months=-2)
```